# How to check that many functions succeeded? - Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a function that I want to run only if 6 prior functions have returned `True` or successful. Currently I do that with the following code:

```
PATHS_GOOD = COUNT_EQUAL = ALL_FILES_PAIRED = VAL_PATHS_GOOD = VAL_COUNT_EQUAL = VAL_ALL_FILES_PAIRED = ALL_CLEAR = False

# Execute functions that change the state of COUNT_EQUAL etc
ALL_CLEAR = PATHS_GOOD and COUNT_EQUAL and ALL_FILES_PAIRED and VAL_PATHS_GOOD and VAL_COUNT_EQUAL and VAL_ALL_FILES_PAIRED

if ALL_CLEAR: 
    #Execute
```

Can I just use shorter variable names? Sure but then no one else will know what that variable is responsible for. This approach won't scale well if I have to keep adding more checks. So how can I possibly make this less verbose and scalable ?

Comment: Put the values in a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally it's not a good idea to pass information around by mutating global variables. Instead you could make the functions return a `bool` based on their success and then use `all()` to check that they all returned `True`:

```
if all((
    paths_good(),
    count_equal(),
    all_files_paired(),
    val_paths_good(),
    val_count_equal(),
    val_all_files_paired(),
)):
    # execute
```

Or alternatively just use `and` between each function call:

```
if (
    paths_good() 
    and count_equal() 
    and all_files_paired() 
    and val_paths_good() 
    and val_count_equal() 
    and val_all_files_paired()
):
    # execute
```

Comment: @S.Ramjit Too large of an topic to cover here, the top hits from the Google search: `python why global variables are bad` should explain it pretty well :)